# Prove that $\chi(G) \leq n$ just when there is a homomorphism from the graph $G$ to $K_n$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I would be very grateful for help with this proof:

> "Prove that $\chi(G) \leq n$ just when there is a homomorphism from the graph $G$ to $K_n$."

we know that: $\chi(G)$ ... denotes the minimum of colors needed for the vertex coloring of the
graph of $n$ vertices

$K_n$ ... is a complete graph of $n$ - vertices

So I divided the proof into 2 parts: a) $\chi(K_n) = n$

- since it is a complete graph of $n$ - vertices, it is necessary to use $n$ colors
- $\deg(v) = n$, for all v belonging to $V(G)$ (the degrees of vertices are preserved when displayed)
- So let there be a homomorphism $G \rightarrow K_n$. Then for every vertex $v$ of $G$ there is exactly one vertex $v'$ of $K_n$ (valid $v \mapsto v´$)
- it follows that the $|V(G)| \leq |V(K_n)|$ (each vertex of $G$ must have something to display on)
- further $K_n$ has $n$ - vertices (from the definition of a complete graph) ... it follows that $G$ must have $\leq n$ vertices
- it follows in conclusion that the number of colors to color the vertices from $G$ is $\leq n$: thus $\chi(G) \leq n$

b) Let $\chi(G) \leq n$ (then the number of vertices is $\leq n$) ... $|V(G)| \leq n$

- further in $K_n$ (complete graph) it is true that we have $n$ vertices, which are all connected to each other (we must have $n$ colors to color this graph $K_n$)
- then there is an injective representation from $G$ to $K_n$

however, I was reproached with the following:

part a) If we have homomorphism, it may not be true that $|V(G)| \leq |V(Kn)|$ and the graph does not have to have less than $n$ vertices

part b) similarly, if we have $\chi(G) \leq n$ then it may not be true that $|V(G)| \leq n$

Note. As an example, we can take the path P on n vertices (then $\chi(P) = 2$).

Would someone please advise me how to rephrase this proof correctly, or how to go a different way ?
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Please do not keep reposting the same post. Edit the original post only. There are now three almost exact copies of this post, two by this poster and one by a poster with a very similar name: [on Feb 21](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4387840), [on Apr 28](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4438317) and [on Apr 30](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4439704).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following general structure for the proof:

a) $\chi(K_n) = n$ (you already did this part)

b) Let $f: V(G) \to V(H)$ be a graph homomorphism and $c: V(H) \to [n]$ be a vertex coloring of $H$. Then $c \circ f: V(G) \to [n]$ is a vertex coloring of $G$.

c) Let $c: V(G) \to [n]$ be a vertex coloring of $G$. Then the following is a graph homomorphism: $f: V(G) \to V(K_n), v \mapsto c(v)$ (where I assume that the vertices of $K_n$ are just the numbers $1, \dots, n$).

Taking these three parts together you get your desired result (why?).

---

As you already mentioned in your question: Your main mistake in your proof seems to have been that you assumed that graph homomorphisms must be injective. This is not the case! For example: If we have a path 1-2-3-4-...-n, then the following is a perfectly fine graph homomorphism:

$$f: V(P) \to V(K_2), i \mapsto i \mod 2$$