# Prove that $\chi(G) \le n$ just when there is a homomorphism from the graph $G$ to $K_n$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I would be very grateful for help with this proof:

> Prove that $\chi(G) \leq n$ just when there is a homomorphism from the graph $G$ to $K_n$.

We know that $\chi(G)$ denotes the minimum of colors needed for the vertex coloring of the graph of $n$ vertices.
$K_n$ is a complete graph of $n$ vertices.

So I divided the proof into 3 parts:

a) $\chi(K_n)=n$

since it is a complete graph of $n$ vertices, it is necessary to use $n$ colors.

$\deg(v)=n$ for all v belonging to $V(G)$ (the degrees of vertices are preserved when displayed)

So let there be a homomorphism $G\rightarrow K_n$. Then for every vertex $v $ of $G$ there is exactly one vertex $v′$ of $K_n$ (valid $v\mapsto v´$). It follows that the $|V(G)|\leq |V(K_n)|$ (each vertex of $G$ must have something to display on)

Further $K_n$ has $n$ vertices (from the definition of a complete graph). It follows that $G$ must have $\leq n$ vertices.

It follows in conclusion that the number of colors to color the vertices from $G$ is $\leq n$ thus $\chi(G)\leq n$.

b) Let $f:V(G)\rightarrow V(H)$ be a graph homomorphism and $c:V(H)\rightarrow [n]$ be a vertex coloring of $H$. Then $c\circ f:V(G)\rightarrow [n]$ is a vertex coloring of $G$.

c) Let $c:V(G)\rightarrow [n]$ be a vertex coloring of $G$. Then the following is a graph homomorphism: $f:V(G)\rightarrow V(K_n),v\mapsto c(v)$ (where I assume that the vertices of $K_n$ are just the numbers $1,…,n$).

Can you help me if this reasoning of the 3 parts of the proof is correct? Or if the claim can be proven otherwise correctly?

Comment: 1. please use MathJax to write mathematics 2. your claim that $G$ has less vertices than $K_n$ is false. For example the path of length $2k$ admits a homomorphism to $K_2$ by sending the vertices alternatingly to 0 and 1.

Comment: Please do not keep reposting the same post. Edit the original post only. There are now three almost exact copies of this post, two by this poster and one by a poster with a very similar name: [on Feb 21](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4387840), [on Apr 28](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4438317) and [on Apr 30](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4439704).

Answer (score 1):

You are right that $\chi(K_n)=n$. A proper proof of this fact would use an induction on the number of vertices, but intuitively it is just because every vertex is adjacent to any other vertices, so all have to have distinct colors.

Recall that a proper $k$-coloring of a graph $G$ is a function $c:V(G)\rightarrow \{1,…,k\}$ satisfying $c(v)=c(w) \implies v \not\sim w$.

Note that you can characterize a complete graph by saying that $u\sim v \iff u \neq v$. Hence the usual definition of a homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow K_n$ in terms of a function $f:V(G)\rightarrow V(K_n)$ satisfying $u\sim v \implies f(u)\sim f(v)$ is in this instance equivalent to the condition $u\sim v\implies f(u)\neq f(v)$, or using the contrapositive that $f(u)=f(v)\implies u \not\sim v$. This is the definition of an $n$-coloring stated above, using the fact that $V(K_n)=\{1,…,n\}$.

Having established this correspondence it is clear that $\chi(G) \leq n$ if and only if there is a homomorphism $G\rightarrow K_n$. This is because $\chi(G)$ is the minimal number $k$ such that there exists a homomorphism $G\rightarrow K_k$ and for $k\leq n$ we always have a homomorphism $K_k \rightarrow K_n$ given by the inclusion $\{1,…,k\}\subseteq \{1,…,n\}$.

Comment: Could you please help me write a sample solution to this evidence because I have to submit it and I have a problem with the correct formulation of the proof.

Comment: No I won’t. There is nothing going on but writing out the definitions and using one contrapositive, so I am confident that you can make it. (Besides the last paragraph my answer is rather formal, so it’s a matter of putting it into your own words) If you have detailed questions about my answer feel free to ask them and I will be happy to answer. But I will not do your exercise sheets for you.